# PHP Is it possible to convert html to Images directly

Tags: php, html, image

Is it possible to convert the html contents including styles to image by php. Please guide me.

Comment: Try googling for "HTML to image PHP". There are many good resources available there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to render it first. For rendering you need something like browser which can handle js, CSS etc. after rendering you take the image. Php is not yet capable of doing such things. But you can achieve it by creating a php extension that uses browser engine and do the task for you. The extension will be like a bridge.

There are many browser engines. Among them you can use *webkit*. It renders quite fast. I Prefer it.

Another thing to know. This extension will take a lot CPU and memory in compared to normal php script.

Comment: Yes I agreed some exe available. Also we can achieve this conversion by creating PDF from html contents and then convert that into Image. But PDF libraries like html2PDF, FPDF, DomPDF, ToPDF are not supporting styles fully.

Comment: I'm telling you to use library. Not the executable or any `system()` call. If you use library, you an turn of the GUI stuff. Just use the rendering engine.